# How to read 大船 when it means "big boat"

Tags: readings

How is 大船 most commonly read?  jisho.org shows three readings, おおぶね, おおふな, and たいせん. There is apparently a place name where it is pronounced おおふな, and that is the pronunciation given by many automatic audio generators, but the meaning it had when I saw it was "big boat."  Is one of the other readings more common in that context?  Or is it still おおふな?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

大船 (おおぶね) is the most common term for a big boat. おおふな　is a city in the Kanto area, but they both use the same kanji. So you better have a good context! You wanna tell a person via text that you wanted to meet at the city and not a big boat!